# Stata plot with information from multiple variables

Tags: plot, stata

I have 10 binary variables- var1, var2,...,var10 answering "yes" or "no" (1 or 0) to a certain question, but under different conditions. I want to create a barplot in stata that shows me the proportion of people who answered "no" for each of the variables (a single plot). How can I do this? If I use the regular barplot command for frequencies

```
graph bar, over(varlist)
```

I get an error because `over()` only takes in a single variable, not a varlist. Something like this is pretty easy to do in R or Python, but I'm not sure how to do this in stata. My data looks something like below:

```
   +-------------------------------+
   | id    var1   var2   var3      |
   |-------------------------------|    
1. |  1    0       0         1     |
2. |  2    1       1         1     |
3. |  3    0       1         1     |
   +-------------------------------+
```

As stated, each person has answered 3 questions (rather, the same question presented in three different ways) with "yes" or "no". I want to generate a single barplot with three bars ("var1", "var2", "var3"), each representing the proportion of people who answered no to the question (so 0.67, 0.33, and 0, respectively, in the example data).

Comment: I will try to please everybody by saying that I didn't downvote but that whoever did so had a case. Without a reproducible example this isn't a good question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reproducible data example here. The Stata tag wiki has very detailed advice on how to give data examples.

Plotting the fraction of zeros directly does not yield to any trick obvious to me as I write, but here is a work-around. The principles for 10 variables aren't different from those for a four-variable example invented here. The main idea is that the default of `graph hbar` (or of `graph bar` or `graph dot`) is to show means, and the mean of a binary variable is a proportion.

```
clear 
set seed 2803
set obs 10 
forval j = 1/4 { 
    generate var`j' = runiform() > (`j' * 0.2) 
}

forval j = 1/4 { 
    generate nvar`j' = 1 - var`j'
    label var nvar`j' "var`j'"
}

graph hbar nvar* , ascategory ytitle(fraction of Nos) name(G1, replace)

statplot nvar*, ytitle(fraction of Nos) name(G2, replace)
```

The `statplot` solution (dependent on installing that command using `ssc install statplot`) is just an alternative. It's a personal view that its immediate result here is closer to a civilised graph than the default of `graph hbar`. But it's not different in principle and you would get closer by spelling out more options directly for `graph hbar`.

Using `graph hbar` rather than `graph bar` is a personal choice.  But if your real data have variable labels or longer names, then space to show either readably for 10 variables could be a medium-sized deal.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, this is my first time posting about stata. What sort of data example do I need to give?

Comment: Understood, but as said the Stata tag wiki explains. I won't write out what is already explained in detail.

Comment: Is it fine now?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that you have given example data. No, in the sense that anyone has to edit that before it becomes Stata data. In essence, the command `dataex` exists to provide data examples (at worst you need to install it using `ssc install dataex`).